# Should moderators get paid?

Tags: discussion

Obviously moderators are a big part of this community. I'm not saying they're the core - because in my opinion the hierarchy should be

1. the people who ask the questions (without them there would be NO SO)
2. the people who answer and/or help out and then
3. the moderators

Nonetheless, it seems that the latter are usually the ones who spend a significant amount of time on the site. I just read the current election and from what I understand you need to be on the site daily for at least 30 minutes or so and have a long standing reputation etc etc.

Now - who pays for all of this? Because SO is a FOR-PROFIT organization. There are banners on the site, SO actively tries to sell to organizations that have an interested in products related to the topics on SO etc etc.

So my argument is this: SO makes money from the activities that moderators help with. Shouldn't they be compensated other than by getting badges?

Also - I know from close-up experience that a lot of IT people are on SO during office hours. And not to ask questions, but to ANSWER them. So effectively stealing time (and money) from their employers. Do we honestly believe that those employers / companies gain more from SO than they lose by having those people on SO?
Of course the same argument can be made for facebook / twitter and what not, but it seems in this case the brain drain is more related to their actual job.

Thoughts?

EDIT - 7 minutes into the question I already have 7 downvotes so the consensus is there, but I'd still like to hear arguments (like Martijn's).

Research says the following (see [this PDF](http://www.iew.uzh.ch/wp/iewwp007.pdf)):

> But we obtain the puzzling result that, when rewarded, volunteers work less.

Comment: Moderators do not get paid, nor should they get paid. It is a *volunteer position*.

Comment: If they were to be paid, then that'd send the wrong message to anyone *wanting* to be a moderator. You change the motivations for vying for such a position. We'd get people that want money, not a great site.

Comment: Thank you, but you're not responding to my arguments

Comment: I am raising points that I feel are important to any discussion about moderator compensation.

Comment: In your case - are you moderating on your employer's time and if not - do you think my point about 'employer time stealing' or the fact that SO  makes money off the Q&A and thus the moderators is invalid?

Comment: No, moderation is a _volunteer_ position. The mods are rewarded by a feeling that they are doing something good for the community, and that they are helping other people.

Comment: The points are entirely moot. How people use and manage their time is their own business.

Comment: There are two important points: 1) SO makes money from this. 2) employers LOSE money from this.

Comment: Other than that - I totally understand and support that moderators want to do this. And I agree that the site wouldn't be the same.

Comment: Volunteers don't work less when _rewarded_, they work less when they're _obligated_, which is what financial compensation does. It's as blurry as it is _really_ fascinating. I'd code my butt off to get an autographed Mojang T-shirt, if doing so meant I'd be producing useful public artifacts. I would not take money from Mojang to code these things, it just wouldn't be as much fun, for example.

Comment: @user1914292: you make huge assumptions about employers there and what relationships there exist between employees and employers. Employers lose money because their employees work on Open Source projects too, but *there are other benefits*. And you may as well try to get Facebook to pay for lost employee time here.

Comment: @user1914292: personally, I am my own employer. So how I spend my time is **literally** my own business.

Comment: I agree with your argument on Facebook, Twitter etc. The point I'm trying to make is that in the case of SO it's about knowledge that's actually used in the job and acquired via schooling/training etc. So it's effectively a brain drain. Less capacity to do the job at hand. What I see (from personal experience) is that there are quite a few people who spend time ANSWERING questions on SO. If they wouldn't do that, they would still benefit from all the knowledge that already exists (same with Google). So the added value from the NEW answers is not in line with the amount of time lost.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Another point is that this is a FOR-PROFIT organization whilst in government hospital or elderly home (where people often volunteer) this doesn't hold. In those cases there's simply not enough capacity. Over here someone eventually takes home the $$$. My feeling says some of that should go to YOU (and in case a mod works on the employers time: the employer).

Comment: What has the commercial status of SE got to do with any of this? They are a facilitator, all this fantastic knowledge would not be here without them. GitHub is a for-profit organisation too. Should they compensate all the OSS developers that make their code available on their site?

Comment: And in plenty of countries hospitals and elderly care facilities are commercial enterprises.

Comment: Other examples: Conventions (the biggest Sci-fi convention is commercial, but there are 1000s of volunteers involved). Music festivals (I am wearing my stage manager T-shirt for a Norwegian music festival today, tons of great memories). Etc. etc. etc. It seems you are fundamentally misunderstanding the nature of volunteering here, and what motivates people to do so.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My point is not that I don't understand volunteering. I volunteer myself (in a variety of ways) and will hopefully keep doing so for years to come. I argue that the money earned should maybe partly go to the people who contribute or on who's time they do it (if not their own time).

Comment: @user1914292: no, because then you are spending that time for *entirely the wrong reasons*. You are no longer volunteering.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I don't say that I want to get paid when volunteering. That's also not the question. I asked - should they get paid. Not: do mods want to get paid.

Comment: @user1914292: Of course it matters if moderators want to be paid. It says something about their reasons for doing the work in the first place.

Comment: @user1914292: and again, by paying volunteers you make them employees or contractors. The relationship changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74807/discussion-between-user1914292-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: Not that I think StackOverflow SHOULD pay the people that contribute to their site a salary, I also don't see why they SHOULD NOT. StackOverflow is a sharing of wealth, so I don't see the harm in sharing things other than knowledge too. It sparks an interesting point that I feel is being carelessly stamped out by people that basically failed to understand user1914292's underlying positive intention before giving it the opportunity to blossom. Please don't let those 'mark you downers' get you down, user1914292. You bring a good point to the table.

Comment: Sure thing they should. It would be much more better do reduce the amount of mods but improve service quality (and reduce their toxicity) by simply paying them a salary.
Stackoverflow is a multi-million company with can afford it, but sure thing they won't do that because they're not interested in it.

Comment: This is a great question! And I learned a lot from the answers that will be not available without this question. Why did you downvote?

Comment: @LernerZhang probably because, as explained by the answers, it'd be a bad move for the community.

Comment: @KevinB What if the question was rephrased to be 'Why should moderators be volunteers?' ? Can this question which is less persuasive but more clarifying be publicly acceptable?

Comment: eh, on meta things get voted on based on popularity most of the time. i doubt it'd get upvoted even if rephrased. The company is quite unpopular these days, and as such, anything suggesting the community relinquish anything to them, such as moderator freedom to serve the community, is going to be poorly received.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Moderation is, for most, a hobby - and an enjoyable one. We would be doing two *bad* things by offering moderators financial compensation:

- We'd be making it a *job*. They already have jobs, they seek these positions because they want to be more effective at what they currently do *for fun*. When you pay, you *obligate*, and things tend to be less fun when you're *obligated* to do them. Even if we stipulated "no obligations", people would *feel* as if there were, because they're generally considerate and to some extent, proud.
- Even though we would *never* tell someone "you get compensation from us, so you should totally side with us when we ask you to do so" - ***paying them could lead to this perception, and would make them much less effective as leaders in their communities***. Moderation is most effective *when placed entirely in the hands of a community*.

Add to that, we could not *possibly* pay over 300 very talented people what they're worth. But, that doesn't mean we don't go out of our way to let them know how much we appreciate them:

- We send free hats (only mods and employees can have these)
- We send free shirts, stickers, mugs
- We've been known to send cupcakes, flowers or more when a mod isn't doing so well
- We tend to 'promote from within' when making new hires. Coming on board didn't feel like getting hired, it felt like getting promoted.
- We make ourselves available and try our best to move furniture out of their way when they want to get stuff done
- We don't hesitate to say ***excellent frigging job!*** - something quite a few people *lack* at their day jobs

When folks use the site is up to them. My employers (typically) didn't mind me spending work time on Stack Overflow, because everyone loved it and used it avidly. Some mods simply can't do things from work, and that's okay - it's up to them and their employer.

What they do on their off time, so long as they find it rewarding and *fun* is purely up to them. If they elect to give some of that time to us, we're honored, and we do our *very* best not to waste it.

For many, that's all they ask, and all they want.

Comment: It's impossible to quantify, but my SO account pre-diamond has definitely been good for my career. Additing a diamond certainly didn't hurt and has probably further helped too.

Comment: I cannot upvote this enough. Being a volunteer mod is the best.

Comment: Absolutely. Being a Stack Exchange mod is its own reward.

Answer (score 15):

Not that I imagine this could or would ever change but here it is:

- I don't want to get paid because that would fundamentally alter the balance of the relationship I have with the site. Right now I do this because I value the site, what it stands for and the collection of knowledge it builds. Getting paid would obligate me to moderate which is s very different thing.
- Labour laws are complex. If you paid only a token sum it would be hard to stay on the right side of tax, minimum wage and all sorts of other obscure rules across multiple countries.
- Even if somehow it did pay a fair wage for moderating duties alone if money was my motivator I still probably wouldn't pick moderation as a career choice. There are far better ways to make money if that's your goal.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there will be lots of very good answers on this but I just wanted to address the issue that **answering** questions is not a productive use of employers' time.

Firstly, without answers nobody would ask the questions. I would suggest that everyone's employers benefit massively from SO. Development time for all of us is reduced by the fact that we now have an enormous repository of quality answers to the types of questions you have every day and we therefore get 'stuck' less. I can't speak for all tags but I well remember trying to build websites in 2003 and let me tell you - I'd be a lot better at this job today if SO had been around then.

Secondly, answering questions can be very valuable.  You start answering a question and then think to yourself 'Hang on...is that really the best way to do that?'.  You question yourself - and if you don't then the community will not be shy about pointing out where you could have improved your answer.  The net result is that by testing yourself in this way you improve your own skills, and very often learn from the other answers that the way you've been doing things is not optimal.

So the bottom line is that employers benefit from SO.  And guess what?  They don't have to pay for that privilege.

Comment: I agree that employers benefit from the knowledge on SO, just like they benefit from Google. But I don't agree that they benefit an equivalent amount of time MORE from SO as is currently being invested by users answering questions. In short: if not a single employee would answer any question anymore - the employers would still benefit almost as much as they do now, simply because the most common questions already have answers in SO and Google.

Comment: That's true - I think it's really about individuals striking a balance.  If someone sat all day long answering questions that would clearly not be good for their employer.  There is a collective responsibility to do it though, just as there is one to help out keep the site clean.  There is also the point that those with rep get their questions answered when they need to ask them, either via bounty or the fact that some users will only answer questions from those with rep as that demonstrates they've already contributed.

Comment: @user1914292: so you are saying that IT is a stale field? We have all the knowledge we could ever want? So anyone learning Swift can just use the answers for other questions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, but I AM saying that the amount of answers NEWLY added doesn't outweigh the cost of addition in cases where it's done on employer's time.

Comment: @user1914292: isn't that up to the employer to decide? If it is *not* OK for the employer, then that's between them and the employee.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there are a lot of companies that ban Facebook, Twitter and what not. I'm sure one day (or was that already yesterday?) there will be companies that explicitly forbid 'bounty hunting on forums' like this one. This doesn't take anything away from the fact that this is a great body of knowledge. It just demonstrates there are two sides to this coin.

Comment: @user1914292: so you discovered that companies already deal with employee time in ways they see fit. So why again should Stack Exchange compensate those employers for employee time? You are basically asking for people to be contracted out here. And that means that there'll be a contractual *obligation* for those employees to work on Stack Overflow tasks. That's the part where the motivations are going to be skewed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm raising an ethical dilemma. I don't have the answer on the implementation. We're living in a new world where lots of these scenarios are emerging. Facebook & Twitter are the big examples of where people got rich by other people contributing. SO is a VC backed organization. Someone will eventually get paid. I argue that maybe you should be one of them. How that's done - that's another question.

Comment: @user1914292: I see no ethical dilemma here at all. And note that most of the money Stack Exchange makes comes from the *careers side*. Not from advertising. Stack Overflow is a way to stack careers.stackoverflow.com with great resumes so companies will pay for access to those. An arrangement I have benefited from more than once now. And that's the thing, *I benefit from the fact that this site exists*. There is a mutual benefit here that would be entirely soured by money changing hands.

Comment: @user1914292: you seem to be entirely hung up on someone managing to make a profit out of facilitating community interchange. If that means that the facilitating can continue and is continually improved (they are motivated to do so to maintain the money flow coming in, not doing so would allow a competitor to take over), then I am *all for it*.